# Ansible - Wrapper of python interpreter

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml

Ansible uses YAML syntax mainly has key-value pairs, where every value can be

a simple value (number or string)

*or*

a list

*or*

a key-value pair(nested)

---

Anchoring a value, Type conversion in YAML is just a pre-processing option.

---

1)

From the data structure aspect,

Is YAML syntax a dictionary of dictionary?

2)

For command: `ansible -m shell 'hostname' all`, Is `ansible` a wrapper of python interpreter? taking multiple command line options...

Answer (score 1):

> From the data structure aspect,
>
> Is YAML syntax a dictionary of dictionary?

No. YAML syntax models a directed graph. Your assumptions on YAML given initially are wrong. In YAML, a value is one of three things:

- A *scalar* (number, string, date, …)
- A *sequence* (list of values)
- A *mapping* (list of key-value pairs where both keys and values are any kind of value)

Since any non-scalar value can contain other non-scalar values, YAML can represent a tree of arbitrary depth – so it's not necessarily a dictionary of dictionaries.

Now, YAML also allows to have an anchor on any value, and reference that value later via alias:

```
anchored value: &anchor My value
alias: *anchor
```

Here, `*alias` references the anchored scalar value `My value`. This can be used to define cyclic graphs:

```
--- &root   # this annotates the root sequence;
- one
- two       # simple sequence items
- three
- *root     # reference to the sequence, meaning that the sequence contains itself
```

Mind that both sequence and mappings are usually started implicitly in YAML syntax. If children are key/value pairs, it's a mapping (first example); if children are list items, it's a sequence (second example). `---` starts the document and is usually omitted.

> For command: ansible -m shell 'hostname' all, Is ansible a wrapper of python interpreter? taking multiple command line options...

See the [man page of the ansible command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ansible). You are probably looking for the `-a ARGS` option. I am unsure what you would consider a *wrapper of the Python interpreter* and you may want to clarify what you actually want to do. Generally, the answer to that is *no*.

Comment: Anchors could be pre-processed before storing the yaml data in to memory, for further usage. If the consumer pre-process anchoring facility in yaml... then there is no need to store YAML file content as directed graph... Isn't it?

Comment: @overexchange YAML is a serialization format; it is designed to be mapped to native data types and a *constructor* (spec'd name of the utility creating the native values) may do all sorts of changes to the data. For example, PyYAML cannot correctly map anchored / nonanchored numbers because Python preallocates space for small numbers and *always* uses those objects for those small numeric values. It is better to think the other way round: Native data structures may contain cyclic structures, so YAML supports serializing those.

Comment: Just wondering... using YAML with Ansible that does not require an agent on target host except ssh server... How ssh server(on target machine) is able to understand the YAML serialization format sent by ansible from control server?

Comment: I have no in-depth understanding of how Ansible works, but I would expect that it parses the YAML locally and then just sends the command(s) to the target. An SSH server is not able to understand YAML; you'd certainly need a tool that does to parse it on the target.

Comment: As I said, Ansible needs to parse the YAML on the host machine to know what you want to do on the target machine. It then uses its modules to do whatever you want it to do on the target machine, but that's *after* loading the YAML, so the target has no need to parse the YAML again. I am also pretty sure that for tasks like creating a user, Ansible does not transfer any code but just executes `useradd` on the target via ssh. Generally, your questions are not really suited for SO's Q&A format, you may want to ask on the [Ansible mailing lists](https://www.ansible.com/community) instead.

Comment: For your point: "Since any non-scalar value can contain other non-scalar values, YAML can represent a tree of arbitrary depth". I would say: dictionary-of-dictionaries can have a non-scalar value that contain other non-scalar value. Isn't it?

Comment: YAML is certainly able to *represent* a dictionary of dictionaries. However, it can also represent other structures.